# Regular expression to capture all the characters after a specific word

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to develop a regular expression to capture the strings after the word 'special-format'.

Example.
This is my input

```
special-format: (%s)
special-format: !%s
special-format: !!%s
special-format: !!%s
```

I would like to get in a group the characters:

```
(%s), !%s, !!%s
```

Comment: Do you want the words after special-characters or special-format, theres an inconsistency in your question and given input

Comment: yes sorry, I edited the question

Comment: If every line looks like that, why don't you just remove all instances of the words `special-format:`.  Alternatively, it sounds like you might want to read up on lookaheads and lookbehinds in regular expressions.

Comment: No, I cannot remove it. I just want to get the strings after the word "special-format"

Answer (score 1):

By using a lookbehind `(?<=)` you can exclude a string from your search, so you can wrap 'special-format: ' altogether. Then you want to match everything after, so you can do a greedy `.*`.

Everything together would be `(?<=special\-format: )(.*)`